# TypeError: get_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, type-error

у меня есть телеграм бот, функционал которого умещается в одном классе:

```
import telebot


class TelegramBot:

    __token = 'my token'
    __bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=__token)
    __chat_id = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.__bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    @__bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def send_greeting(self, message):
        self.__chat_id = message.chat.id
        greeting = f"Hello, {message.from_user.full_name}!"
        self.__bot.send_message(chat_id=__chat_id, text=greeting)

    def send_info(self, some_info):
        self.__bot.send_message(chat_id=self.__chat_id, text=some_info)
```

Первый метод предназначен для того чтобы поприветствовать пользователя и получить id чата, для дальнейших отправок сообщений этому пользователю. Второй метод не зависим от того, пишет пользователь боту или нет, и будет запускаться из другого класса. В первом методе при использовании аргумента `self`, получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: get_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Если же не буду его использовать, то не смогу отправить приветствие и не смогу записать id чата в переменную класса, и в моем втором методе бот не будет знать нужный id. Можно ли отправить приветствие без аргумента `self`, и как мне во втором методе узнать id чата с пользователем? Если не трудно, помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Советую для начала ознакомиться с ООП в Python, с тем, что такое `self`, и как работает раздобытый вами бот. Никакой аргумент `self` вы не используете, да и ошибка вам не про него говорит. Вы неверно сам вопрос ставите.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Сергей, спасибо за комментарий, как я понял, self, это объект класса TelegramBot, ошибка мне говорит о том, что аргумент message, то есть сообщение от пользователя должно стоять на первом месте и быть единственным аргументом данного метода. Аргумент  self, то есть экземпляр класса мне нужно использовать(другого способа я не знаю), чтобы послать приветствие, и чтобы записать Id чата. Пожалуйста, поправьте если я что-то не так сказал.

Comment: Это полный код?

Comment: Здравствуйте, nomnoms12, спасибо за ваш комментарий! Для этого файла - да. У меня есть ещё один файл, в котором я и буду запускать бота.

Comment: Неважно на сколько файлов вы разбили код. Приведите его весь (в части, относящейся к вызову данного класса и его методов, конечно), и приведите текст сообщения об ошибке полностью. У вас же там явно не одна строка в ней, да и ссылка есть на конкретную строку с ошибкой. По вашему первому ответу я даже не знаю, что сказать. Приводите всё остальное, тогда выше вероятность, что кто-то ответит.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще класс бота?

Comment: Здравствуйте ещё раз, Сергей, спасибо, я учту все ваши рекомендации при следующих своих вопросах.

Comment: Здравствуйте, oleksandrigo, я подумал что так будет удобнее)

Comment: @gooduser поверь это скорее костыль, а не удобство

Comment: Доброе утро, oleksandrigo, то есть в данном случае можно обойтись без класса? Но ведь ООП подразумевает работу именно с объектами классов, верно? Поправьте, пожалуйста, если я неправильно говорю.

Comment: ООП подразумевает работу с классами и их экземплярами, да. Но зачем вам тут ООП в таком применении? (извините, что за другого участника пока отвечаю:-)

Comment: Добрый день, Сергей) Я думаю если учесть то что моя программа будет масштабироваться, и я приму во внимание ответ, написанный ниже, переделав свой код, то есть смысл оставлять класс, не так ли? Пожалуйста, поправьте, если я что-то неправильно говорю)

Comment: А вот теперь очередь @oleksandrigo, т.к. стало понятнее, зачем тут класс

Comment: хэх, да, действительно было бы неплохо=)

Comment: @gooduser берд, каким чудом вам поможет впихивание своего бота в класс? Я думаю это не тот случай, где ООП приносит пользу, скорее вред. Вы что так, что этак будете делать хендлеры и вписывать их в файлы.

Comment: здравствуйте, oleksandrigo, спасибо за ваш комментарий! Если честно, я не могу с вами спорить по этому поводу, так как опыта в программировании у вас куда больше, поэтому действительно, возможно в моем случае можно обойтись без класса. Если я замечу что этот класс мне как-то мешает, и без него будет удобнее, то я обязательно его уберу=)

Comment: good user, обычно советуют наоборот. Если вы видите преимущества от ООП, то его применяете, если нет - то функциональный подход. А так можно всё что угодно сделать и тем и другим подходом.

Comment: Добрый вечер, Сергей, спасибо за комментарий! Да, я с вами полностью согласен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком использовании декоратора `message_handler` есть принципиальная проблема, с проявлениями, которой вы столкнулись.

Она заключается в том, что вы можете создать больше одного экземпляра `TelegramBot` в программе. Подумайте, если вы так сделаете, у которого из них бот должен вызывать `send_greeting` при команде старт?

`message_handler` сам по себе не предназначен для вызова на несвязанных методах объекта. Несвязанный метод, это метод, который просто так вызвать нельзя, чтоб его вызвать нужен экземпляр класса, который нужно передать первым параметром. `TeleBot` при вызове метода с декоратором `@message_handler` передает только `message`, о вашем объекте `TelegramBot` он ничего не знает (а тем более объектов может быть много).

Как решить?

Есть два способа. Первый это использовать только статические данные в классе:

```
class TelegramBot:

    @__bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    @staticmethod
    def send_greeting(message):
        TelegramBot.__chat_id = message.chat.id
        greeting = f"Hello, {message.from_user.full_name}!"
        TelegramBot.__bot.send_message(chat_id=TelegramBot.__chat_id, text=greeting)
```

Этот подход по сути аналогичен использованию глобальных функций и переменных, за тем исключением, что они находится в классе.

Второй способ - это использовать связанные методы. И заворачивать связанные методы класса в декоратор вручную, например в конструкторе:

```
class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.send_greeting = self.__bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])(self.send_greeting)
        self.__bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        
    def send_greeting(self, message):
        self.__chat_id = message.chat.id
        greeting = f"Hello, {message.from_user.full_name}!"
        self.__bot.send_message(chat_id=__chat_id, text=greeting)
```

Еще несколько замечаний общего плана:

1. у вас __bot - статический, т.е. один на все экземпляры класса. Не уверен, что вы это специально сделали.
2. то же самое касается и `__chat_id`

Я понимаю, что скорее всего вы не будете создавать больше одного экземпляра в программе. Но все же у этого решения есть минусы:

1. Если вдруг решите создать два бота, то статические `__bot` и `__chat_id` будут проблемой
2. Использование статических полей и полей экземпляра одновременно без четкого разделения обязанностей приводит к путанице.

Одним словом, я бы сделал оба поля полями экземпляра, т.е.:

```
class TelegramBot:

    __token = 'my token'

    def __init__(self):
        self.__bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=__token)
        self.__chat_id = 0
        self.__bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ, Роман! Действительно, я новичок в этом языке и не заметил ряд проблем у меня в коде. Теперь, благодаря вам я все понял:) ещё раз спасибо и хорошего вечера!